# How to run appium java testNG scripts without appium server?

Tags: android, automation, appium

I came to know that, We can upload appium test scripts and apk to cloud testing tools like AWS? device farm, testdroid.com. But I would like to run in my mobile itself without any need of computer[appium server, eclipse], Is there anyway to run appium scripts within just mobile. Thank you :) Ask me if you did not get clarity in question.